# A space with each point having infinite neighbours?

Tags: limits, metric-spaces

I have a *naming problem*. I want to refer to a metric space $X$ in which each point $x$ has infinitely many neighbours. That is, for every point $x$ each neighbourhood has infinitely many points of $X$. For example $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{Q}^n$ with the any Minkowsky metric would be such a metric space.

Is there a **name** for such a metric space?

At the moment, I have only found certain properties. For example, that the space I am referring to is a space in which each point is a limit point. Great, but does $X$ have some concrete name?

Comment: Well a space in which every  point has a finite neighbourhood is called locally finite. Maybe the appropriate name would be locally infinite? Since when $X$ is $T_1$, this exactly characterizes your class of spaces, maybe there was no real need to attach a terminology to such an object.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur thanks, "locally infinite" sounds OK, it is a good argumentation. But what do you mean with "Since when $X$ is $T_1$, this exactly characterizes your class of spaces, maybe there was no real need to attach a terminology to such an object". Could you expand on it?

Comment: You can call it a metric space with no isolated points. A point $p$ in any topological space $X$ is isolated iff $\{p\}$ is open. A point in a metric space is isolated iff it has a finite nbhd.

Comment: I think that "pure" mathematicians do not fully grasp the relevance the set I describe in my question (i.e., a perfect set). Such set is what any common person would understand as something *continuous*: that you can approach any point (or state) in the set by as many in-between states as you want, as finely as you desire. The usual definition of continuity in topology, is solid and good for mathematics, but it is counter intuitive for common persons living in the real world and, IMHO, it is counterintuitive in 'weird' sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already been argued successfully that a T1 space (and a metric space a fortiori) satisfies your condition if and only if it has no isolated points. Other terms for a space without isolated points are *perfect* space and, perhaps, *dense-in-itself* space.

As far as extending the discussion to general topology goes, it should be pointed out that, despite the formulation, the condition is not actually local. In fact, for a topological space $(X,\tau)$ the following are equivalent:

1. every $x\in X$ has a fundamental system of (not necessarily open) neighbourhoods that have infinite cardinality.
2. every non-empty open set is infinite.

I don't know of a term for (2) and, seeing as the property if fairly easy to formulate, I think that there isn't any.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the best terminology for my described set: **perfect metric set**. Certainly, the most compact expression, better than *metric set without isolated points*, and much better than *metric set where every neighbourhood has infinite elements* ;). I found a good article wikipedia [perfect set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set). In fact, a perfect set is defined for subsets: it is a *closed* subset $A \subset X$ without isolated points; yet, for sets $X$ that are not subsets, the condition of being closed is fulfilled by definition ($X$ is both open and closed set).

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken in this statement, but I meant that if $X$ is $T_1$, then $X$ is 'locally infinite' if and only if $X$ has only limit points. Since this seems long for the comments, I write it here.

Like you said, you have one implication. For the converse direction assume that $X$ is $T_1$. Let $x$ be a limit point of $X$. Assume towards contradiction that there exists a finite neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. Then

$$ U=\{x\}\sqcup\{ x_1,...,x_k \}. $$

$\{x_j\}^c$ is open for each $1\leq j\leq k$, and so $U\cap \cap_{j=1}^k \{x_j\}^c=\{x\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. This contradicts the fact that $x$ is a limit point.

This argument shows that if $X$ has only limit points and is $T_1$, every neighbourhood must be infinite, i.e., $X$ is 'locally infinite'.